# In Flutter pubspec.yaml file updated the version to 1.1.0+3 but on uploading to playConsole, still error version code 1

Tags: android, flutter, google-play-console, release-management

I've tried to upload an updated **aab** to the playConsole for my application but have got the following error:

```
Upload failed You need to use a different version code for your APK or
Android App Bundle because you already have one with version code 1.
```

I've tried to update the version code to 3 in the `pubspec.yaml` but I'm still getting the same version after uploading the latest generated aab/apk.

Answer (score 2):

Finally resolved it!

The issue was with the android/local.properties file which was not getting updated. I manually updated the version code here and got around the problem.

[image]

Comment: This happens sometimes if you skip any version code in sequence. Recently I faced the same and I **deleted**  `local.properties`  and then clean and rebuild will keep continue versioning.

Answer (score 1):

Did you try to do a flutter clean before building the second time? The previous build might have been cached.

Other then that, check your android/app/build.gradle file there should be something like this there that sets the version:

```
def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response, I checked the android/app/build.gradle and everything was as expected.